# Ansible, YAML, and Syntax

Tags: python, networking, yaml, ansible

I am trying to create an Ansible configuration that will run a playbook and utilize a single variable file to create a single configuration with multiple items. I am trying the following syntax and it is failing. How can I fix this?

**vars/main.yml**

```
---
or1host1:

      - interface: 1/1
        description: or1-servertest
        TRUNK: true
        allowedVlans: 101-103
        NVLAN: true
        nativeVLAN: 101
        ACCESS: false
        accessVlan: none
        PC: true
        pcNUM: 10

      - interface: 1/2
        description: or1-servertest2
        TRUNK: false
        allowedVlans: 101-103
        NVLAN: false
        nativeVLAN: 101
        ACCESS: true
        accessVlan: none
        PC: true
        pcNUM: 10
```

**templates/nxos.j2**

```
{% for interface in or1host1 %}
interface Ethernet{{item.interface}}
description {{item.description}}
{% if item.TRUNK %}
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan {{item.allowedVlans}}
  spanning-tree port type edge trunk
{% if item.NVLAN %}
  switchport trunk native vlan {{item.nativeVLAN}}
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% if item.ACCESS %}
  switchport mode access
  switchport access vlan {{item.accessVlan}}
  spanning-tree port type edge
{% endif %}
{% if item.PC %}
  channel-group {{item.pcNUM}} mode active
{% endif %}
  no shut
{% endfor %}
```

**I am receiving the following error when running the playbook.**

```
PLAY [Generate Configuration Files] ******************************************* 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [nxos | Generate configuration files] *********************************** 
fatal: [localhost] => {'msg': "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: One or more undefined variables: 'str object' has no attribute 'interface'", 'failed': True}
fatal: [localhost] => {'msg': 'One or more items failed.', 'failed': True, 'changed': False, 'results': [{'msg': "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: One or more undefined variables: 'str object' has no attribute 'interface'", 'failed': True}]}

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/home/gituser/site.retry

localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=
```

0

Comment: What sort of errors are you getting?

Comment: I edited my original question to take in account some changes mentioned below and included the following errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out, see example below.

**~/vars/mail.yml**

```
---
nxos:
- {hostname: testhost}
interfaces:
- {ACCESS: 'true', NVLAN: 'true', PC: 'true', TRUNK: 'true', accessVlan: '1', allowedVlans: 500-600,
  desC: serverhost-1005, intF: eth1/1, nativeVLAN: '56', pcNUM: '23'}
- {ACCESS: 'true', NVLAN: 'true', PC: 'true', TRUNK: 'true', accessVlan: '1', allowedVlans: 500-600,
  desC: serverhost-1006, intF: eth1/2, nativeVLAN: '56', pcNUM: '23'}
```

**~/templates/nxos.j2**

```
HOST: {{item.hostname}}

-----------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------

{%for i in interfaces %}
interface Ethernet{{i.intF}}
  description {{i.desC}}
{% if i.TRUNK %}
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan {{i.allowedVlans}}
  spanning-tree port type edge trunk
{% if i.NVLAN %}
  switchport trunk native vlan {{i.nativeVLAN}}
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% if i.ACCESS %}
  switchport mode access
  switchport access vlan {{i.accessVlan}}
  spanning-tree port type edge
{% endif %}
{% if i.PC %}
  channel-group {{i.pcNUM}} mode active
{% endif %}
  no shut
!
{% endfor %}
```

**Configuration**

```
HOST: testhost

-----------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------

interface Etherneteth1/1
  description serverhost-1005
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 500-600
  spanning-tree port type edge trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 56
  switchport mode access
  switchport access vlan 1
  spanning-tree port type edge
  channel-group 23 mode active
  no shut
!
interface Etherneteth1/2
  description serverhost-1006
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 500-600
  spanning-tree port type edge trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 56
  switchport mode access
  switchport access vlan 1
  spanning-tree port type edge
  channel-group 23 mode active
  no shut
!
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things here. First, you really have to take care of indention, when you're not in JSON mode. When you indent a list item with 4 items, all other list items are required to have the same number of spaces. Your second item has 6 spaces which would be an syntax error, if there was not the completely loose element `interface: 1/2`, which is the main problem here, as it doesn't make sense and there is no way how this could be parsed into a data structure. In a list you can have any number of list items, but no loose properties on the same level. I think you meant to have it inside the 2nd list item. With both corrected it looks like this:

```
---
or1-host1:
  - { interface: 1/1, 
      description: or1-servertest, 
      TRUNK: true, allowedVlans: 101-103, 
      NVLAN: true, nativeVLAN: 101, 
      ACCESS: false, accessVlan: none, 
      PC: true, pcNUM: 10
    }

  - {  interface: 1/2,
       description: or1-servertest2, 
       TRUNK: false, allowedVlans: 101-103, 
       NVLAN: false, nativeVLAN: 101, 
       ACCESS: true, accessVlan: none, 
       PC: true, pcNUM: 10
    }
```

While JSON is a valid subset of YML I find it way more readable to stay strictly with YML syntax, which then looks like:

```
--- 
or1-host1:
  - interface: 1/1
    description: or1-servertest
    TRUNK: true
    allowedVlans: 101-103
    NVLAN: true
    nativeVLAN: 101
    ACCESS: false
    accessVlan: none
    PC: true
    pcNUM: 10

  - interface: 1/2 
    description: or1-servertest2
    TRUNK: false
    allowedVlans: 101-103
    NVLAN: false
    nativeVLAN: 101
    ACCESS: true
    accessVlan: none 
    PC: true
    pcNUM: 10
...
```

In your template though you won't be able to access `1/1` or `1/2` like that. Maybe you want to loop over the interfaces in the template? I'm not sure.

```
{% for interface in or1-host1 %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

I think you will have to rename `or1-host1` as this doesn't look like a valid variable name due to the hyphen, `or1_host1` would work.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I edited my question above and posted the errors I am getting.

Comment: I think the remaining issue is the notation of how you access the attributes. Try `item["interface"]` instead of `item.interface` and the same for the other attributes.

Comment: Looks like this might work, however, I need to get my if statements figured out. Running the play book with the changed variable names gives me this error: fatal: [localhost] => {'msg': "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: One or more undefined variables: 'TRUNK' is undefined", 'failed': True}
fatal: [localhost] => {'msg': 'One or more items failed.', 'failed': True, 'changed': False, 'results': [{'msg': "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: One or more undefined variables: 'TRUNK' is undefined", 'failed': True}]}

Comment: But `TRUNK` is defined and in your condition you use `tiem["trunk"]`? If `TRUNK` is an optional element you can test for its existence with `if "TRUNK" in item`.